# submit appears twice jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

this is my html:

```
<td rowspan="2">
    <input id="mysubmit" type="submit" value="send" />
</td>
```

I use following references:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
```

The problem is that I see the submit button twice (1 - in classic html view, 2 - jquery mobile button style)

If I manage to make the 1-st dissapear then the jquery mobile doesn't submits.
If I leave the 2-nd using css tricks, then it appears alone only when I do refresh.

This is how it looks:
http://nesjeck.net/nesjeck/mobile/images/submit.jpg

Thank you

Comment: You are using 1.4.2 CSS with 1.2.0 JS. Pick a version and use both CSS and JS from the same version.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you do go with 1.4.2 (recommended) you should probably use at least v 1.9.x of jQuery.